# Emails via Python - Paste contents of excel/csv as a formatted table onto the mail body

Tags: python, email

I am trying to send mails via Python using smtplib. My main concern is to get the contents of a csv/excel and paste the data as it is(tabular format) onto the mail body of the email being sent out. I have the following snippet ready to search for the file and print the contents on the shell. How would I get the same output onto a mail body?

```
from os import listdir
import csv
import os

#Search for a csv in the specified folder
directory = "folder_path"

def find_csv_filenames( path_to_dir, suffix="Data.csv" ):
    filenames = listdir(path_to_dir)
    return [ filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith( suffix ) ]

filenames = find_csv_filenames(directory)
for name in filenames:
    datafile=name
    print(name)

path=directory+'//'+datafile

#Read the selected csv
with open(path,'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=' ',quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

TIA for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html?highlight=stringio#StringIO) instance, say csvText and instead of print use

```
csvText.write(", ".join(row)+"\n")
```

The final newline is necessary, because it is not automatically added as by print. Finally (i.e. after the loop) calling csvText.getvalue() will return what you want to mail.

I would also suggest not to glue file specification together by yourself but call os.path.join() instead.